# Rearrange a character string

Tags: regex, r

I have a character vector where some entries have a certain pattern at the end. I want to remove this pattern from the end and put it in front of the rest.

Example:

```
#My initial character vector
names <- c("sdadohf abc", "fsdgodhgf abc", "afhk xyz")
> names
[1] "sdadohf abc"   "fsdgodhgf abc" "afhk xyz" 

#What I want is to move "abc" to the front
> names
[1] "abc sdadohf"   "abc fsdgodhgf" "afhk xyz"
```

Is there an easy way to achive this or do I have to write an own function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's add one more string to your vector, one with multiple spaces between the text.

```
names <- c("sdadohf abc", "fsdgodhgf abc", "afhk xyz", "aksle   abc")
```

You could use capturing groups in `sub()`.

```
sub("(.*?)\\s+(abc)$", "\\2 \\1", names)
# [1] "abc sdadohf"   "abc fsdgodhgf" "afhk xyz"      "abc aksle"
```

Regex explanation courtesy of [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vP9yJ8/1):

- `(.*)` 1st Capturing group - matches any character (except newline) between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
- `\\s+` matches any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]` between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- `(abc)` 2nd Capturing group - `abc` matches the characters `abc` literally, and `$` asserts position at end of the string

When we swap the groups in `"\\2 \\1"`, we bring the second capturing group `abc` to the beginning of the string.

Thanks to @Jota and @docendodiscimus for helping to improve my original regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
sub("(.*) \\b(abc)$", "\\2 \\1", names)
```

`.*` is a greedy match. It will match as much as it can before finding the string ending with `abc`.

`.*` is in first captured group`(\\1)`

`abc` is in second captured group`(\\2)`

We can just interchange their position using `\\2 \\1` to find our resultant string

Comment: Could you please explain what this does, and why it answers the question.

Comment: @Maljam is that a legit question(I smell sarcasm)

Comment: I understand what it does, but I think it's preferable to post full answers and explain why it works for those who do not know what this line of code means/does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a split method.  We split the 'names' by one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by 'abc' (`(?=abc)`), loop through the `list` with `vapply`, reverse (`rev`) the `list` elements and `paste` it together.

```
vapply(strsplit(names, "\\s+(?=abc)", perl=TRUE), function(x)
                paste(rev(x), collapse=" "), character(1))
#[1] "abc sdadohf"   "abc fsdgodhgf" "afhk xyz"      "abc aksle"
```

#### data

```
names <- c("sdadohf abc", "fsdgodhgf abc", "afhk xyz", "aksle   abc")
```